# How many London underground stations you can visit without passing through the same station twice?

Tags: graph-theory

If you can start anywhere and only travel on the lines shown in the official map (http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/standard-tube-map.pdf) (including overground, DLR, Emirates Air Line and weekend-only District Line routes), what is the maximum number of stations you can visit without passing through a station more than once?

Comment: Finding the maximum length simple path in a graph is known as [the Longest Path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).